# SocketIO Java Client to get emitted data by a NodeJS's express web server

Tags: java, node.js

Looking for a simple SocketIO Java Client, which can receive data emitted by a NodeJS's express web server. I am able to receive data on a particular topic from NodeJS and .NET clients, but not able to get any sample code for Java.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) is the Github page for Socket.IO's Java client. There is an example under the `Usage` heading in the README.md.

Comment: Thanks Theob for your quick response, I am new to Java, so i am not getting how to use this Git code and build it. If you can guide me what are all the things require and how to build the application or JAR from given code, it would be a great help for me.